# React-admin automatically insert "_eq" to query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-admin

When call setFilter function react-admin keep inserting "_eq" op to my query
This is my custom filter code

```
const TestFilter = () => {
  const { filterValues, showFilter, setFilters, displayedFilters } = useListContext();
  const handleClick = (target: HTMLInputElement) => {
    if(target.checked) {
      console.log('clickk')
      setFilters({
        "library_indicator_tags": {
          "library_indicator_tag_name": {
            "name": {
              "_like": target.value
            }
          }
        }
      }, displayedFilters);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SimpleForm>
      <ReferenceArrayInput
        key="library_indicator_tag_name"
        reference="library_indicator_tag_name"
        source="library_indicator_tags"
      >
        <CheckboxGroupInput optionValue="name" onClick={(e) => handleClick((e.target as HTMLInputElement))} />
      </ReferenceArrayInput>
    </SimpleForm>
  );
};
```

Here's what i got in my query
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALBSL.png)

How can i remove this "_eq" op from my query
This is what i expected in my query
[expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUAz7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code: this `_eq` parameter is added by your `dataProvider`. Check at the implementation of `dataProvider.getList()`.